# Событие submit и обработчик события

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Можно ли при появлении события сабмит на форме, использовать собственный обработчик чтобы произвести валидацию? Прочитал на форумах - вроде как должно отрабатывать. В итоге отрабатывает частично - если форма заполнена верно и произошел сабмит, то вызовется обработчик, который я передал в виде колбэк. Если же форма заполнена неверно и засабмичена, то мой обработчик не вызовется и браузер отработает по своему. Т.е. никаких вариантов добраться до валидации вручную.

Пробовал сие на г**нокоде, который привожу ниже. Как быть, если я всё таки хочу провести валидацию по событию сабмит на форме?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" action="#" method="POST">
            <input type="number" min="10">
            <button type="submit"></button>
        </form>
        <script>
            var somefun = function () {
                console.log('happend');
            };
            var elementForm = document.querySelector('#form');
            elementForm.addEventListener('submit', somefun);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли при появлении события `submit` на форме использовать собственный обработчик, чтобы произвести валидацию?

```js
var elementForm = document.querySelector('#form');
// Нужно поймать событие "e"
elementForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Остановить форму от посылки на сервер
  //------------------------------------------------------------
  // Your validation goes here
  console.log('happened');
});
```

```html
<form id="form" action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="number" min="10">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что если форма неверно заполнена, то до вашего колбэка дело вообще не дойдет, соответственно валидацию таким образом не произвести

Comment: @Semerkin  дойдет до колбека даже если неправильно заполнена. `preventDefault` останавливает обработку и посылку формы, в вашем коде не было перехвата события сабмит `preventDefault`.

Comment: У меня не доходит до колбэка)))

Comment: @Semerkin не доходит с перехватом события?

Comment: конечно. Я сейчас разобрался, что если форма невалидна, то будет событие инвалид на инпутах. А это событие не всплывает, так что обработчик точно не вызовется

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в `<form>` атрибут `onsubmit = "return formValidation()"`, а в функции используйте `return true;` для отправки формы на сервер или `return false;` для отмены.

```js
function formValidation() {
  alert("Валидация формы");
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return formValidation()">
  <input type="number" min="10">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для отключения проверки браузером можно воспользоваться атрибутом [`novalidate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-novalidate) на форме

```js
var somefun = function() {
  console.log('happend');
};
var elementForm = document.querySelector('#form');
elementForm.addEventListener('submit', somefun);
```

```html
<form id="form" action="#" method="POST" novalidate>
  <input type="number" min="10">
  <button type="submit">btn</button>
</form>
```